# Series which is a product of sequences which converges, but diverges when one of them is shifted by 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to find two sequences $\{ a_n \}, \{ b_n \}$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges, $\{ b_n \}$ is bounded, $\sum a_n b_n$ converges, but $\sum a_{n+1} b_n$ diverges.  If this is not possible, a sketch of the proof would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $$a_{2n}=(-1)^n/n, a_{2n+1}=0, b_{2n}=1, b_{2n+1}=(-1)^n$$

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: I take it's not possible if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely?

Comment: @Accum if the series $a_n$ converges absolutely then $\sum |a_n c_n|  \le C \sum |a_n|< \infty$ for any bounded $|c_n|<C$ so applying this with $c_n=b_{n-1}$ shows that $\sum a_{n+1}b_n$ converges absolutely too